# Firebase on("value") not getting called after push

Tags: firebase

I have an array of a few hundred objects, each object (JSONified) looks like:

```
{
  "progress" : 0,
  "sold" : false,
  "frame" : 1,
  "frameData" : {
    "filename" : "file.ma",
    "filepath" : "scenes/subscene",
    "projectPath" : "/path/to/project",
    "projectName" : "TRELCG",
  },
  "winningBid" : {
    "bid" : 31536000,
    "hostname" : "localhost"
  }
}
```

Doing a garden-variety push:

```
var base = new Firebase("https://bkvo9o89wxl.firebaseio-demo.com")

var ref = base.push(array);

ref.on("value", function(snap) {
   var data = snap.val();
   if (data!==null && Array.isArray(data)) console.log(snap.val().length);
}
```

The on("value") callback *never* fires. However if instead, I push a shorter/subset of the array e.g.

```
var subset = array.slice(0,50);

ref = base.push(subset);
```

This works as expected and the callback fires.

Even weirder still, if I remove the "frameData" property from the object, e.g.

```
{
  "progress" : 0,
  "sold" : false,
  "frame" : 1,
  "winningBid" : {
    "bid" : 31536000,
    "hostname" : "localhost"
  }
}
```

And push the *full* array, the callback fires as usual.

I've used Firebase on many projects over the last one year and done this exact thing thousands of times, on arrays even larger than this but this one's really got me stumped.

Am I missing something, what gives?

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in your console? I have a hunch that there's something in that object that is invalid in Firebase. For instance perhaps you have an undefined somewhere, or a key with a '.' in it?

Comment: And if not, can you throw up a jsfiddle or give me access to a test page so I can try this myself? 
Also - we were hit with a DDOS attach around the time this was posted. Perhaps your Firebase was affected.

Comment: Andrew, it most likely was the DDOS cause I had many very strange problems, especially when dealing with transactions during the period, which all seem to have -- now -- magically resolved themselves. 

E.g. in the above, I found this weird "permutation" where if I added a few properties with long random string values, the callback would fire then!

Comment: Perhaps, as a suggestion, you guys can have somewhere on your site letting us know when your servers are experiencing issues, cause the troubling thing is no Error object was ever passed to my transaction callbacks, or to the on() callbacks when they did fire.

Comment: @adrian you can follow http://www.twitter.com/firebasestatus for updates.

Comment: Was the root cause of this figured out? I'm experiencing the same thing now. My on('value') callback is not being called when I perform a push.set().